# How to push object to a new array with button click on ngFor table in angular 8

Tags: html, arrays, angular

I how to arrays, one(`array1`) has some objects while the other(`array2`) has a list of objects that I want to choose from and push to `array1`.

**.html**

```
<div class="forArray1">
 <table >
   <tr *ngFor="list1 of array1">
       <td>{{list1.name}}</td>
       <td><button (click)=removeFunction()>Remove</button><td>
    </tr>
 <table>
</div>
<div class="forArray2">
  <table >
   <tr *ngFor="list2 of array2">
   <td>{{list2.name}}</td>
   <td><button (click)=addFunction()>Add</button><td>
   </tr>
 <table>
</div>
```

How to push the row object from arry2 list to arry1 list after clicking on the "Add" button on a specific object? Something like get by ID and push.

**json**

```
array1 = [
    {
     "type": "toyota", 
     "year": "2013"
    }]

***************************************

array2 = [
    {
     "type": "toyota", 
     "year": "2013"
    },
    {
     "type": "audi", 
     "year": "2010"
    },
    {
     "type": "honda", 
     "year": "2014"
    },
    {
     "type": "ford", 
     "year": "2018"
    }]
```

**.ts**

```
array1 = [];
array2 = [];

//add an obj to array1 and delete it from array2
addFunction() {
       //TODO
}

//it will remove the an obj from array1
removeFunction(){
      //TODO
}
```

How to complete the functions? Suggestion on better approach is also fine.

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular, this is just javascript ;)

Comment: if array methods are unfamiliar to you, I suggest you read up on arrays in javascript, as a whole: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @AJT82, well sorry, I'm working on angular and this came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app.component.html** :

```
<div class="forArray1">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let list1 of array1; let i=index;">
            <td>{{list1.name}}</td>
            <td><button (click)=removeFunction(i)>Remove</button><td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</div>
<div class="forArray2">
    <table >
        <tr *ngFor="let list2 of array2; let i=index;">
            <td>{{list2.name}}</td>
            <td><button (click)=addFunction(i)>Add</button><td>
        </tr>  
    <table>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts** :

```
addFunction(index){
    // Add selected item to first array
    this.array1.push(array2[index]);
    // Remove item from second array
    this.array2.splice(index,1);
}

removeFunction(index){
    // Replace item in second array
    this.array2.push(array1[index]);
    // Remove item from first array
    this.array1.splice(index,1);
}
```

I assume you want to restore a removed item back into second array. If not, just remove the line `this.array2.push(array1[index]);` in remove function.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abauyw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

.html

```
<div class="forArray1">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let list1 of array1">
            <td>{{list1.type}}-{{list1.year}}</td>
            <td><button (click)=removeFunction(list1)>Remove</button>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>



<div class="forArray2">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let list2 of array2">
            <td>{{list2.type}}-{{list2.year}}</td>
            <td><button (click)=addFunction(list2)>Add</button>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

.ts

```
addFunction(item) {
    let index = this.array2.findIndex(x => x.type == item.type  && x.year == item.year)
    this.array1.push(this.array2[index])
    this.array2.splice(index,1)
  }

 removeFunction(item) {
    let index = this.array1.findIndex(
      x => x.type == item.type && x.year == item.year
    );
    this.array1.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it also works. I will vote this code, thanks!